Are Magento & Adobe Commerce the same integration?
I'm with a Payments Services Provider and we currently have a plugin for Magento. I've only now learned that Magento is now Adobe Commerce.
I have a potential client that's asked if we have a plugin for Adobe Commerce. Is Adobe Commerce a totally new integration that we need to create a plugin for, or is the same as Magento, just rebranded?
Many thanks for any insight.
Cheers!

Adobe Commerce is essentially the same platform as Magento, with some additional features and improvements that come from Adobe's ownership and integration into its broader ecosystem. Here's a bit more detail to clarify:
Magento and Adobe Commerce:
Magento was originally an open-source eCommerce platform.
Adobe acquired Magento in 2018, and since then, Magento has been rebranded as Adobe Commerce for its commercial (paid) version.
The open-source version of Magento still exists and is referred to as Magento Open Source.
Differences and Compatibility:
Adobe Commerce (formerly Magento Commerce) includes additional features not found in the open-source version, such as advanced marketing tools, customer loyalty programs, and enhanced security features.
However, at the core, Adobe Commerce is built on the same codebase as Magento Open Source, meaning the underlying architecture and functionality remain largely the same.
Plugin Compatibility:
If your plugin is compatible with Magento 2, it should generally be compatible with Adobe Commerce, given that Adobe Commerce is built on Magento 2.
There might be some specific features or integrations unique to Adobe Commerce that could require adjustments or additional development work to fully support all of Adobe Commerce's capabilities.
Recommendations
Testing: It would be prudent to thoroughly test your existing Magento plugin on an Adobe Commerce instance to ensure full compatibility.
Documentation Review: Review Adobe Commerce's documentation to identify any new features or changes that might affect your plugin.
Client Communication: Assure your potential client that your plugin is compatible with Magento 2, and based on that, it should work with Adobe Commerce. Inform them that you will verify compatibility to ensure seamless integration.
By doing these steps, you can confidently support clients using Adobe Commerce without significant redevelopment, assuming your current Magento plugin is up to date and adheres to Magento 2 standards.
